# How to select inner div in an unordered list

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to create a navigation menu with markup as follows:

```
<ul id="ul1">
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a>
            **<div>**
                <p>SOME STUFF</p>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 1.1</a><**div** class="innerdiv"></div></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 1.2</a><**div** class="innerdiv"></div></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 1.3</a><**div** class="innerdiv"></div></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 1.4</a><**div** class="innerdiv"></div></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        .
        .(WITH MORE <LI>'S OFC :))
        .
</ul>
```

Now, I want to make the outer div visible when I hover on Link 1...This is easily done using CSS:

```
#navbar ul li div
{
    min-width:500px;
    min-height:130px;
    background-color:#dfdfdf;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:32px;
    visibility:hidden;
}

#navbar ul li:hover div
{
    visibility:visible;
}
```

Next I want that inner div be visible only when I hover on inner links like link 1.1,1.2..
This is causing problems cause I'm using #(id)-selector taking the #navbar as base ID and this is causing the inner divs to inherit the css from outer div ...THAT IS TO SAY THAT WHEN I HOVER ON OUTER LINKS THE BEHAVIOUR OF THE INNER DIV CHANGE TOO WHICH I DON'T WANT...if u understand what I mean..

I WANT THAT OUTER DIV SHOULD BE VISIBLE WHEN I HOVER ON OUTER LINKS(LINK 1,2,3) AND INNER DIV BE VISIBLE WHEN I HOVER ON INNER LINKS(LINK 1.1,1.2,1.3)
SCREENSHOT OF THE NAVMENU

[image: SCRREN SHOT OF THE MENU:]
God this is confusing...
Kindly help in this respect by telling how to specifically select the inner div's or tell a workaround using JS or Jquery....currently I'm using the selectors

```
#navbar ul li div ul li div , and
#navbar ul li div ul li a:hover div
```

Comment: It is confusing. What if you move this logic to JQuery's code? http://api.jquery.com/hover/, then you can easily select inner div's with find()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your div is initially not displayed:

```
#navbar div {
  display: none;
}
```

You can make them visible when the container `LI` is hovered:

```
#navbar li:hover > div {
  display: block;
}
```

The `>` operator is used to select direct descendants, so here only the `div` elements that are immediate child nodes of the `li` that is currently being hovered will be made visible. For more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors

Answer (score 0):

I would just change the visibillity of the list item.

ul li ul li {
....
}

Furthermore i don't see your "navbar" id anywhere? Neither a ..

Comment: navbar is a div in which that unorderedlist is wrapped like so <div id="navbar"><ul>.......</ul></div>